# SAS: In proc sql, how does one preserve the variable label when performing operations on that variable?

Tags: sql, sas

In SAS proc sql, how do I preserve the label of myvar (in myoldtable) when performing the following simple operation?:

proc sql;
   create table mytable as
   select myvar*1.5 as myvar
   from myoldtable;
   quit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to just update myoldtable instead? That will do the math and preserve your variable name...

```
proc sql;
    update myoldtable
    set myvar=myvar*1.5;
quit;
```

Of course, if you're really stuck on getting the new table, you could always do this:

```
proc sql;
    create table mynewtable as
    select * from myoldtable;

    update myoldtable
    set myvar=myvar*1.5;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use 'lable' option for you requirement.

```
proc sql;
create table mytable as 
   select myvar*1.5 as myvar label="Label for myvar" format=best. 
   from myoldtable;
quit;
```